# Access nested object in freemarker

Tags: freemarker

I'm using freemarker to generate an xml output and having issues accessing properties of nested objects I came across this article on ["Stack Overflow"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10807756/how-to-use-freemarker-to-template-nested-pojos), but I still can't get properties and get an invalid reference expression.

Code Samples

```
public class Inc {
private String id;
private List<BusinessAddress> businessAddress;
....

//get and setters for properties
.... 
}

//------------------------------
public class BusinessAddress{
private String id;
private Address details;
....

//get and setters for properties
....
}

//------------------------------
public class Address {
private String id;

//get and setters for properties
....

}

//--------------------------------------
public class FreemarkerTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try
    {

    Inc inc = ......;


    Template freemarkerTemplate = null;
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.setClassForTemplateLoading(FreemarkerTest.class, "/");

    String templateFile = "freemarker/template.ftl";
    StringWriter out = new StringWriter();
    freemarkerTemplate = configuration.getTemplate(templateFile);       
    Map<String,Object> contextPropsExpressioned = new HashMap<String,Object>();

    contextPropsExpressioned.put("payload", inc);
    freemarkerTemplate.process(contextPropsExpressioned, out);        

    System.out.println(out);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

and the freemarker template is

```
<#list payload.businessAddress as businessAddress>

    <EntityLocation>
        <nc:Location id="${businessAddress}Sub${details.id}" dataid="${businessAddress.id}">
        </nc:Location>
    </EntityLocation>

</#list>
```

of even

```
<#list payload.businessAddress as businessAddress>

    <EntityLocation>
        <nc:Location id="${businessAddress}Sub${getDetails().id}" dataid="${businessAddress.id}">
        </nc:Location>
    </EntityLocation>

</#list
```

the exception I receive is

```
FreeMarker template error:

The failing instruction (FTL stack trace):
----------
==> ${details.id}  [in template "freemarker/template.ftl" at line 172, column 97]
----------
Tip: If the failing expression is known to be legally null/missing, either specify a default value.....

Java stack trace (for programmers):
----------
freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: [... Exception message was already printed; see it above ...]...
```

Any assistance would greatly be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `${businessAddress.details.id}`?

Comment: Yep, that was the first version I tried and I got the same error as well: 

"The following has evaluated to null or missing:
==> businessAddress.detail"

Comment: So maybe you have null values somewhere in that list or in `Address` field.

Comment: I went through all test cases and just realized that one of the addresses was not being initialized through the json conversion. I did revert back to ${businessAddress.details.id} and now its formatting everything correctly. Added some additional checks in the template as well for null values even though this scenario should never happen. Thanks for the help Aleksandr

Comment: You can answer your own question, this will help future visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up using what Aleksandr had suggested as well as added null checks.

```
<#list payload.businessAddress as businessAddress>

   <#if (businessAddress.details??) >
       <EntityLocation>
          <nc:Location id="${businessAddress.details.id}" dataid="${businessAddress.id}">
          </nc:Location>
       </EntityLocation>
   </#if>
</#list>
```

Comment: Doesnt work for me, I dont have null values still Freemarker cant see nested properties. Any idea?

Comment: sir what if my nested key is like "capital-value" then what?